# How can I shoot a bullet with the space bar?

Tags: python, pygame

Here’s my code:

```
import pygame, os

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display
d = win.set_mode((1200, 600))

class player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.speed = 2

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= self.speed

    def move_right(self):
        self.x += self.speed


class bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = 10
        self.speed = 20


    def shoot(self):
        x = p.x
        y = p.y
        self.shooting = True
        while self.shooting:
            d.fill((98, 98, 98))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            y -= self.speed
            pygame.draw.circle(d, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), self.radius)
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(100)
            win.update()

            if y <= 0:
                self.shooting = False


b = bullet()
p = player(600, 500, 50, 30)
while True:
    d.fill((98, 98, 98))
    p.draw()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pass

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            b.shoot()
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            p.move_left()
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            p.move_right()

    win.update()
```

This is what I could come up with after a few trial and errors, but it is really ineffective. Firstly, the player disappears when I press the space bar. I guess this is obvious as I have a different loops for shooting and player, but I don’t know how to get around it and implement both shooting and player in the same loop.

The second problem I am having is breaking the `while self.shooting:` loop. I tried breaking it when y reaches a certain point by doing this:

```
 if y <= 0:
     self.shooting = False
```

But this doesn’t break. Instead, it restarts the loop all over again.

Another weird problem I am having is that every time I move the mouse (slightly fast) or press a bunch of buttons at once, it breaks the `while self.shooting` loop.

Comment: Take a look to @cookertron answer to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554633/how-to-draw-a-line-in-pygame-that-moves-up-the-screen?noredirect=1#comment105278156_59554633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to firing bullets is to store the positions of the bullets in a list (`bullet_list`). When a bullet is fired, add the bullet's starting position (`[start_x, start_y]`) to the list. The starting position is the position of the object (player or enemy) that fires the bullet. Use a `for`-loop to iterate through all the bullets in the list. Move position of each individual bullet in the loop. Remove a bullet from the list that leaves the screen (`bullet_list.remove(bullet_pos)`). For this reason, a copy of the list (`bullet_list[:]`) must be run through (see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)). Use another  `for`-loop to `blit` the remaining bullets on the screen:

```py
bullet_list = []

while run == True:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullet_list.append([start_x, start_y])

    for bullet_pos in bullet_list[:]:
        bullet_pos[0] += move_bullet_x
        bullet_pos[1] += move_bullet_y
        if not screen.get_rect().colliderect(bullet_image.get_rect(center = bullet_pos))
            bullet_list.remove(bullet_pos)

    # [...]

    for bullet_pos in bullet_list[:]
        screen.blit(bullet_image, bullet_image.get_rect(center = bullet_pos))

    # [...]
```

See also [Shoot bullet](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_keys_and_keyboard_event.md#shoot-bullet).

---

Please note, that class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
(See [Style Guide for Python Code - Class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names))
That means it has to be `Player` and `Bullet` rather than `player` and `bullet`

You have an application loop, so use it. All the objects are continuously updated and drawn in the main application loop, in each frame.

The class `Bullet` do not need any loop. The constructor has to have parameters for the position (`x`, `y`). Further it needs on method which changes the position and one which draws the bullet:

```py
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.radius = 10
        self.speed = 10
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed#

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(d, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
```

Use a list of `bullets`. Create a new bullet when <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed. Move the bullets (`update`) in every frame an [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) a bullet if it is out of the window. Draw the remaining bullets in every frame:

```py
bullets = []

# [...]
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]
        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append(Bullet(p.x+p.width//2, p.y))

    # [...]
    for b in bullets:
        b.update()
        if b.y < 0:
            bullets.remove(b)

    # [...]
    for b in bullets:
        b.draw()
```

Furthermore use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) use to get the state of the keys in every frame and to update the position of the player:

```py
while run:

    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        p.move_left()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        p.move_right()
```

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, os

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display
d = win.set_mode((1200, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.speed = 2

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= self.speed

    def move_right(self):
        self.x += self.speed


class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.radius = 10
        self.speed = 10
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed#
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(d, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


bullets = []
p = Player(600, 500, 50, 30) 

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
        
    # handel events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==  pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append(Bullet(p.x+p.width//2, p.y))

    # update objects
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()        
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        p.move_left()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        p.move_right()
    for b in bullets:
        b.update()
        if b.y < 0:
            bullets.remove(b)

    # clear display
    d.fill((98, 98, 98))

    # draw scene
    for b in bullets:
        b.draw()
    p.draw()

    # update display
    win.update()
```